# CATALYST: Recursive inheritance detected in package 'Class::C3::Componentised' during global destruction

Tags: perl, inheritance, recursion, catalyst

'm a Perl and Catalyst-Framework Newbie and try to learn it with this tutorial: http://search.cpan.org/~mramberg/Catalyst-Runtime-5.7001/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Tutorial/CatalystBasics.pod - I did everything exactly like in the Tutorial.
Now I want to start the Server and get an Error. I don't know how to handle it.

```
MyApp$ ./script/myapp_server.pl 
[debug] Debug messages enabled
[debug] Statistics enabled
[debug] Loaded Config     "/home/.../Catalyst/MyApp/myapp.conf"
Couldn't instantiate component "MyApp::Model::MyAppDB", "Recursive inheritance detected     in package 'DBIx::Class' at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Class/C3/Componentised.pm line 154.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Catalyst/ScriptRunner.pm line 50.
Recursive inheritance detected in package 'Class::C3::Componentised' during global destruction.
```

Don't know what to do. Maybe you have an Idea?
Using Perl 5.18.2, Catalyst::Runtime5.90071 and Catalyst::Devel 1.39

Answer (score 0):

You're using an older version of the manual (5.7001) than of Catalyst (5.90071). The latest manual is found via:

http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Catalyst-Manual/

Check the model definition you'd get from that versus what you have. Alternatively can you provide the code for your MyApp::Model::MyAppDB?